# Problem with running react over ip address

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, https

React app compile successfully and when I open it with `localhost` there is no problem. but when I open it with ip I get error.

Here is react compile successfully:

[image]

And error when I open app with `http://192.168.1.101:300`

[image]

It seem chrome try use `https` instead of `http`.

I try with other port and same problem.

**UPDATE**

I also notice this:

[image]

Comment: Do you have any firewall restrictions?

Comment: No, I don't think. When I try with other project, it works.

Comment: is your system time correct? and try clearing the cache or launch in incognito mode.

Comment: I tried them before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just remove `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'">`
 from `head` in html. and problem solved.